# Find substring in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I have a model `mer20` that contains lists of numbers as strings (called leading and lagging), delimited by `|`. E.g.

`235833|1457541|2244166|2824350|3219744|3343546`

What I'm trying to do is build an query so that I can grab records with **exact** matches to the individual numbers.

I've tried this:

`mer = where("leading like ? OR lagging like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")`

But it also gets objects with the query as a substring, which I don't want!

Additionally, how would I go about checking if any of these numbers are between two others (a,b)?

**Final Solution:**

```
mer = where("leading = ? OR lagging = ? OR leading like ? OR lagging like ? OR leading like ? OR lagging like ? OR leading like ? OR lagging like ?", query.to_i, query.to_i, "#{query}|%", "#{query}|%", "|#{query}|", "|#{query}|", "%|#{query}", "%|#{query}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include that it has to either start at the start of the string (ie no `%` at the beginning) or start with a `|` ... likewise it has to end at the end of the string (ie no `%` at the end) or end with a `|`

Comment: Would you be able to include an example? I assume I shouldn't be using `like` in this instance?

Comment: sorry - example left as an exercise for the reader here ;) Give it a go... Yes, you should be using `like`, but you should also be using `or`

Comment: I've got [this](https://gist.github.com/lutrasdebtra/82cfeb736f87d85b0fe1) but I have the same problem as before, if I type `1` in my search, I get all the objects with a `1` in the numbers! Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes... you still have `"%{query}%"` as an option... which you shouldn't have. Remember: 1) either it starts with beginning-of-string (ie doesn't have a leading %) OR it starts with `|`) 2) either it ends with end-of-string (ie it has no % at the end) OR it ends with `|`